# C# run a batch script without a new window and redirect all (standard/error) output to a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file, process

I have a batch script that launches the mariadb in console mode, so it looks likes this:

**run-mariadb.bat**

```
@echo off
cd /D mariadb-10.1.14-win32\bin && mysqld.exe --console
@pause
```

Using a C# WinForm app, I'd like to launch this batch script and get all output onto a RichTextBox.

This is the code I have so far:

```
// Configure db server process
Process dbServer = new Process();
dbServer.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
dbServer.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c start /wait run-mariadb.bat";
dbServer.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
dbServer.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
dbServer.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
dbServer.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
dbServer.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(HandleDBServerOutput);
dbServer.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(HandleDBServerOutput);
```

These are my helper methods:

```
string FormatOutput(string message)
{
    return string.Format("[ {0} ] : {1}",
        DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(),
        message);
}

void HandleDBServerOutput(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
            dbLogsRTB.AppendText(FormatOutput(e.Data));
    }));
}
```

I start the process like this:

```
// Start database server
dbServer.Start();
dbServer.BeginOutputReadLine();
dbServer.WaitForExit();
```

When the above executes, a new command prompt window is created and the mariadb is running in there. Any ideas why `dbServer.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;` is being ignored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The help for `start` starts off with:

> Starts a separate window to run a specified program or command.

In other words, by running `start` as part of your command, you'll launch a new window.  You can verify this by running `start /wait run-mariadb.bat` from a command prompt.  It launches a new window to run the command.

Consider changing your command to be simply:

```
dbServer.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c run-mariadb.bat";
```

To just run the command without starting a new console process.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have done the trick, ignore my previous deleted comment. Now, the launch is working, but I am not getting any output, but I know mariadb server in fact is running (I could connect to it). Another thing, the whole app UI appears to have frozen, is it because of the waitforexit line? I am trying to run a server in a hidden console and redirect output to my own RTB, how can I solve this?

Comment: Yes, if you run this on the GUI thread, the GUI thread will lock up while the `WaitForExit` line waits for completion.  You can keep a reference to the dbServer in your form and check the `HasExited` from time to time, or sign up `Exited` event, whichever makes more sense for your application.

Comment: Do you mean I need to enable `EnableRaisingEvents` ?

Comment: Yes, if you want to go the route of hooking up a `WaitForExit` handler, then you need to enable `EnableRaisingEvents` so the handler will be called.